# bash cp full list of attributes

Tags: bash, cp

I don't know where to get the full list of attributes that you can put in "--preserve" or "--no-preserve" in the "cp" command using "bash". The only ones I have found are these:

```
--preserve[=ATTR_LIST]
              preserve the specified attributes (default:
              mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible additional
              attributes: context, links, xattr, all
```

I have done more research on the internet but have not found it. Can you provide it to me? Thank you.

Comment: is there some reason to expect there'd be others than what the manual lists?

Comment: Because in the manual "ATTR_LIST" is mentioned, only there is no special section that lists all the values it can contain. Are you sure the manual lists them all?

Comment: well it does have two lists, the default preserved attributes, and the possible additional attributes, right there in your quote. I'm just wondering if there's any reason to assume those lists would be lacking. Though to answer your question, no, I am not _sure_ the manual lists them all, one would have to check the program source for that. Similarly, I'm also not _sure_ it doesn't have other undocumented options, or that it doesn't just sometimes replace copied files with photos of kittens.

Comment: I'm relatively confident that the manual is mostly on-point though, and don't see a need to question it without a good reason. Which is why I didn't ask this question. But you did, and usually people don't just ask random questions without context, so again, I wonder if there was a reason to ask that.

Comment: Sorry, I made hasty conclusions regarding the attributes of cp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you’re referring to the GNU coreutils version of `cp`, the `--preserve` options are described in the [`cp` Info manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/cp-invocation.html#index-_002dp-3). The list given by `cp --help` is complete: `mode`, `ownership`, `timestamps`, `context`, `links`, `xattr`, and the meta-option `all`.